# Is it possible to select all anchor tag in a web page which contains target="_blank" using javascript / jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to select all the anchor tag in a web page which contains target="_blank" attribute.

I have searched other questions but couldn't find a suitable solution.

```
<a href="https://wclink.co/link/22523/121674/4/83501" 
data-store="Frontgate" data-vars-store="Frontgate" 
data-vars-outbound-link="https://wclink.co/link/22523/121674/4/83501" rel="nofollow" 
target="_blank" 
data-gtm-trigger="callout_product_link_button"><span>$30</span> from <span>Frontgate</span></a>
```

I want to have a list or array object which contains all  **target="_blank"** in the whole page, using javascript / jquery.

Thanks You

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

```
document.querySelectorAll('a[target="_blank"]')
```

like this

```js
document.querySelectorAll('a[target="_blank"]').forEach(lnk => console.log(lnk.href))
```

```html
<a href="x">x</a><br/>
<a href="https://wclink.co/link/22523/121674/4/83501" 
data-store="Frontgate" data-vars-store="Frontgate" 
data-vars-outbound-link="https://wclink.co/link/22523/121674/4/83501" rel="nofollow" 
target="_blank" 
data-gtm-trigger="callout_product_link_button"><span>$30</span> from <span>Frontgate</span></a><br/>
<a href="y">y</a>
```

Comment: what about a `document.querySelectorAll('a[target="_blank"]')`

Answer (score 2):

You can select every anchor tags with this jquery code:

```
$('a[target="_blank"]').dosomething();
```

so if you want to select all tags with specific attribute:

```
$('--your html element here--[--your element's attribute--="--specific value--"]')
```

you can do this with css too:

```
 a[target="_blank"]{
     //css here
 }
```

Comment: will it select all the anchor tag that contains target = "_blank" ? I tried on a page , but shows only a single link. And I removed the dosomething(). 

How can I get all the tags ?

Comment: what to do you want to do with that.could you please provide more information?

Answer (score 0):

For Javascript

```
document.querySelectorAll('[target="_blank"]')
```

For jquery

```
$('[target="_blank"]')
```